# month is set to january in oracle 11g irresptive of any month

Tags: oracle11g

I know its a bit weird question. I am passing date dd-mm-yyyy format from my UI and storing that into oracle 11g. but strange thing happened that it is storing it as JAN month only i.e if I pass 16-10-1992 or 10-03-1992 it is storing it as a 16-JAN-1992 way only. please let me know what silly thing I missed out?
Here's my HibernateUtil.java

```
package assignment.util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import assignment.service.UserEntity;

@Component
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactorty=null;
public  static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
    if(sessionFactorty==null){
        System.out.println("inside hibernate Util");
    Configuration configuration=new Configuration();
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(UserEntity.class);

    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "myDb");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "Vihang616");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:myDb");
    /*SchemaExport schemaExport=new SchemaExport(configuration);
    schemaExport.create(true, true);*/
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder srb=new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
    srb.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry=srb.build();
    sessionFactorty=configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

    }
    return sessionFactorty;


}
public static void shutDown(){
    if(sessionFactorty!=null)
    sessionFactorty.close();
}
}
```

Here's my USerService.java

```
package assignment.service;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import assignment.model.User;
import assignment.util.HibernateUtil;
import assignment.util.ServiceUtil;

@Component
public class UserService {


    public Integer saveUser(User user) {
    Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    UserEntity userEntity=new UserEntity();
    userEntity.setDob(ServiceUtil.stringToDateConverter(user.getDob()));
    userEntity.setEmail(user.getEmail());
    userEntity.setUserName(user.getUserName());
    session.save(userEntity);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    System.out.println("ID:"+userEntity.getUserId());
    session.disconnect();
    HibernateUtil.shutDown();

    return userEntity.getUserId();
    }

}
```

Here's my SerivceUtl.java

```
package assignment.util;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class ServiceUtil {
public static Date stringToDateConverter(String string){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
    System.out.println("dob:"+string);
    Date date=new Date();
    try {
    date=sdf.parse(string);


    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("exception in parsing date");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}
}
```

Here's My Entity class

```
package assignment.service;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
@Table(name="UserDb")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -6620152467355557520L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer userId;
@Column(nullable=false)
private String userName;
@Column(nullable=false)
private String email;
@Column(nullable=false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dob;
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public Date getDob() {
    return dob;
}
public void setDob(Date dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}
public Integer getUserId() {
    return userId;
}
public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}



}
```

Comment: Please show some code!

Comment: What code you want to see??its spring MVC code nothing much related to queston

Comment: Where are you persisting to the table?  What DB library are you using?  Nobody here can help you without some concrete details.

Comment: Have added db related details.. please let me know if you need more

Comment: Not sure of why you are converting dob from JPA/java native Date type to string.  Assuming table column in oracle is a DATE type? Why not just:  userEntity.setDob(user.getDob());

Comment: yes in oracle dob is date type from UI I am taking it as a string format

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130436/discussion-between-lowcool-and-oldprogrammer).